# Regular expression to extract pairs of values from stty -a output

Tags: regex, perl

I am sure there is better way to extract rows and columns from a string

This is an example of what `$var` may be set to

```
my $var = "speed 38400 baud; rows 20; columns 96; line = 0;"
```

The following program works, but I'm looking for a better regular expression

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

#use strict;
#use warnings;

my $var = `stty -a`;

if ( $var =~ /speed\s+38400\s+baud\;\s+rows\s+(\d\d)\;\s+columns\s+(\d\d\d|\d\d)/ ) {
    printf $1;
    printf "\n";
    print "$2\n";
}
```

#### output:

```
20

96
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
my $var = `stty -a`;
if (my ($rows, $cols) = $var =~ /rows\s+(\d+);\s+columns\s+(\d+)/) {
  print "$rows\n";
  print "$cols\n";
}
```

The `+` in the regex means "one or more of the preceding." It makes the regex much simpler than trying to handle it like `\d\d|\d\d\d`. If you really want "two or three of the preceding" you can write expressions like `\d{2,3}`.

If you're looking for a more standard way of determining the size of the current terminal window, you might take a look at the various `Term::Size` modules on CPAN.

Comment: Definitely consider using `Term::Size` there. That's a far better way to ask the terminal how big it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should process the output of `stty` as a general string

Here's an example that processes your sample string. I have used `Data::Dump` to display the hash that is built from the pattern match, and the two columns -- `rows` and `columns` -- that you seem to be interested in are also shown

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

use Data::Dump;

#my $var = `stty -a`;
my $var = 'speed 38400 baud; rows 20; columns 96; line = 0;';

my %comms = do {
    my @comms = grep $_, split /\s*;\s*/, $var;
    map /(\S*) [\s=]* (.*) /x, @comms;
};

dd \%comms;

say $comms{rows};
say $comms{columns};
```

#### output

```
{ columns => 96, line => 0, rows => 20, speed => "38400 baud" }
20
96
```